# Reference field/Reference table for currency and quantity fields

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary, sap-smart-forms

What are reference field and reference table, why we need to specify for currency and quantity fields, where we can check the reference field/reference tables for our requirement?

I am creating a smart form for purchase order item data so, I need quantity and price fields, so what fields I have to take and what reference fields I have to specify?

Comment: What documentation have you read. What did you not understand. (SCNR)

Comment: I did not read any documentation, Iam new learner, I did not understood the concept of How to specifying the reference field/reference table for currency and quantity fields.

Comment: So try to read it and highlight places that are not clear to you. This is not a learning hub.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference field should be the the field containing the relevant currency or unit for the amount in your field. This can be within the same table or in another table (see [SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/12a2d87e6c531014bec0e63ea0208c21/7.0.33/en-US/cf21ea5d446011d189700000e8322d00.html) for technical details).

It's easy to understand if you use an example. Your SmartForm may contain an offer with the following text: "The price of 5 paper is 2." That won't help much, because the recipient would be wondering: Is it 5 sheets of paper, 5 boxes of paper, 5 kilograms of paper? And do I pay in Euros, US-Dollars or Bitcoins?

That's why you need a reference field, containing the unit and/or the currency. The amounts does not make any sense on it's own or may cause problems if someone starts adding them up under wrong assumptions etc.